# How can i write query in laravel with where clause?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Store below json record in database table field 'contact_info', Datatype is text

```
{
  "invoice":{
    "number":"gthy",
    "invoiceDate":"2019-12-25 17:20:08",
    "invoiceDueDate":"2020-01-01 17:20:08",
    "paymentTerms":"7"
  },
  "company":{
    "name":"Test ",
    "address":"Test",
    "city":"Test",
    "state":"Test",
    "country":"Test",
    "pincode":"Test",
    "email":"Test@gmail.com",
    "currency_code":"USD"
  },
  "sender":{
    "name":"Test",
    "address":"Test",
    "city":"Test",
    "state":"Test",
    "country":"Test",
    "pincode":"Test",
    "email":"Test"
  }
}
```

I need to applied where condition with 'invoiceDueDate' this field in Laravel. So how can i write query for this? Please suggest me.

Comment: in which array you want to store `contact_info`?

Comment: I need to applied where query in record field 'invoiceDueDate'.

Comment: so you want to add extra field in invoice array right and it is contact_info ok?

Comment: No. Write select query with where condition to find data which Invoice Date is 2019-12-25 17:20:08 in laravel

Comment: `Contact::where('contact_info->invoice->invoiceDueDate', '2020-01-01 17:20:08')->get()`

Answer (score 0):

The following query can be used:

```
$contacts = Contact::where('contact_info->invoice->invoiceDueDate', '2020-01-01 17:20:08')->get()
```

To get all records with the `invoiceDueDate` after a certain date:

```
$contacts= Contact::where('test->invoice->invoiceDueDate', '>=','2020-01-01')->get()
```

An alternative without the need of JSON support:

```
Contact::where('contact_info', 'like','%"invoiceDueDate":"2020-01-01 17:20:08"%')->get()
```

checkout the json [querying documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#json-where-clauses) of laravel.

Comment: Give error to me as below
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>'$."invoice"."invoiceDueDate"' = ? order by `id` desc' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `generated_invoices` where `status` in (1) and `contact_info`->'$."invoice"."invoiceDueDate"' = 2019-12-25 17:20:08 order by `id` desc)

Comment: what mysql version are you using @GaurangDangi? Use `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` and check the `version` field in the result set

Comment: contact_info data type is text. i have used whereJsonContains also.

Comment: Version : 5.5.62.

Comment: You will need to use `MySQL 5.7` to use json query's @GaurangDangi An alternative would we to use text filtering but that isn't as clean.

Comment: No any other ways? for this version.

Comment: I added an alternative, it isn't as flexible so I would recommend upgrading your mysql version for more sophisticated filtering @GaurangDangi

Comment: Ok. One way is filter data in foreach loop but that is not compatible for large number of data.

Comment: yep and it is quite memory intensive, what kind of filtering do you want to apply to the date? Exact dates or dates after date x?